# Can values defined in MANIFEST.MF be accessed programmatically?

Tags: java, android, jar, manifest

Can I access the values defined in a java manifest from code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the file with [`JarFile`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) and then call `getManifest()` to get the [`Manifest`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html). After that you can access the attributes appropriately.

Comment: THis is even more flexible. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

Many of the values in the MANIFEST.MF can be accessed programmatically without having to find and/or open the jar file itself.

The class [`java.lang.Package`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html) provides access to the [`ImplementationTitle`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getImplementationTitle()), [`ImplementationVendor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getImplementationVendor()), [`ImplementationVersion`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getImplementationVersion()), [`SpecificationTitle`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getSpecificationTitle()), [`SpecificationVendor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getSpecificationVendor()) and the [`SpecificationVersion`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getSpecificationVersion()).

Information about signed classes can be found using the [`CodeSource`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html) class, which can be retrieved via `Class`[`.getProtectionDomain()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getProtectionDomain())[`.getCodeSource()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource())

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know if thats also available to android?

Comment: Personally I don't know, but it seems like it: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks. I checked it again and found that Jon's solution provides more flexiblity and is available on android as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/manifesto) of reading the main attributes from a JAR's manifest *in situ*. It's handy for checking up on what's actually there. In outline,

```
var jar = new JarFile(name);
var manifest = jar.getManifest();
var map = manifest.getMainAttributes();
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
    System.out.println(e.getKey()
        + ": " + e.getValue());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use following way to detect External Jar/SDK MANIFEST.MF Info. We could use this info for detecting Jar version etc. Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html

```
  public void getSDKInfo() {
    Package pkg = Manifest.class.getPackage();
    String specTitle = pkg.getSpecificationTitle();
    String vendor = pkg.getSpecificationVendor();
    String version = pkg.getSpecificationVersion();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`com.jcabi.manifests.Manifests`](http://manifests.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.7.5/com/jcabi/manifests/Manifests.html) utility class from [jcabi-manifests](http://manifests.jcabi.com/index.html). Using this class you can read all available MANIFEST.MF files with one liner:

```
String name = Manifests.read("Foo-Name");
```

Also, see this article: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/07/03/how-to-read-manifest-mf.html