# Get manifest-file from executed JAR

Tags: java, jar, manifest

Let's say I have:
core.jar
client.jar (contains main-method) (uses core.jar)
super_mega_client.jar (uses core.jar, client.jar)

To run my program I use "java -jar super_mega_client.jar"
How could I get the manifest-file from "super_mega_client.jar" knowing nothing about it's name and content?
Actualy I need to create an util in core.jar which will work with the jar, executed with "java -jar ***.jar"

---

OK, here is proper question:
I have **main.jar** with main-method (lets say in **my.app.Main** class)
I also have **fisrt.jar**(with some classes and resources) and **second.jar** (with some other classes and resources). Both have no main-classes, both have "**main.jar**" in CLASSPATH, both have Main-Class property defined as "**my.app.Main**".
I can run my app by executing "*java -jar first.jar*" or "*java -jar second.jar*"
In my `my.app.Main.main(String[] args)` method (contained in **main.jar**) I want to know the name of the executed jar (I want to get either "**first.jar**" or "**second.jar**")
How could I do it?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198525/can-values-defined-in-manifest-mf-be-accessed-programmatically) question.

Comment: I know neither jar-name, no any class name. I only know that jar was used in "java -jar *.jar" command.

Comment: +1. Using the answer cited, you can search the manifest of each potential JAR, e.g. `find /path/to/jars -name '*jar' | xargs manifest`

Answer (score 1):

In any jar that declares its main class, the location and name is fixed by the standard to `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

You can retrieve the manifest file using the `jar` command that comes with the Java SDK (any zip tool that you can run from the command might suffice too) by running:

```
jar -xvf anyjar.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

this will create the META-INF directory and put the manifest file in it. You can leave out the -v if you want less verbose output.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understand what you need here, but check out this article (for instance)

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/resources.html

You ask the CLASSLOADER (so use a class you have loaded already and request what classloader it used is probably good enough) to load the resource for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-verbose` option of the `java` command to see the names of all loaded classes.