# Using Java to read a .jar manifest file

Tags: java, jar, manifest

so I am trying to see if a .jar is valid or not, by checking some values in the mainfest file. What is the best way to read and parse the file using java? I thought of using this command to extract the file

```
jar -xvf anyjar.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

But can I just do something like:

```
File manifest = Command.exec("jar -xvf anyjar.jar META-INF/MAINFEST.MF");
```

Then use some buffered reader or something to parse the lines of the file?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198525/can-values-defined-in-manifest-mf-be-accessed-programmatically/2198542

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with using the `jar` tool is that it requires the full JDK to be installed. Many users of Java will only have the JRE installed, which does not include `jar`.

Also, `jar` would have to be on the user's PATH.

So instead I would recommend using the proper API, like this:

```
Manifest m = new JarFile("anyjar.jar").getManifest();
```

That should actually be easier!

Comment: Oh wow that does make more sense. Wait so I also am using a Command.exec("code that extracts jar"). Is there an easier way to do that as well.

Comment: Yes. But there must already be a question on that on Stackoverflow.

Comment: So far I'll I've been able to find is using the command prompt but this link seems like it would work but it looks kinda compicated lol. Why can't it be simple like jarfile.run() or something. http://www.programcreek.com/2012/08/unzip-a-jar-file-in-java-program/

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is more complicated. But you can just copy and paste it, so, who cares?

Answer (score 5):

The Package class at *java.lang.Package* has methods to do what you want. Here is an easy way to get manifest contents using your java code:

```
String t = this.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationTitle();
String v = this.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

I put this into a static method in a shared utility class.The method accepts a class handle object as a parameter. This way, any class in our system can get their own manifest information when they need it. Obviously the method could be easily modified to return an array or hashmap of values.

call the method:

```
    String ver = GeneralUtils.checkImplVersion(this);
```

the method in a file called *GeneralUtils.java*:

```
public static String checkImplVersion(Object classHandle)
{
   String v = classHandle.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
   return v;
}
```

And to get manifest fields-values other than those you can get via the Package class (e.g. your own Build-Date), you get the Main Attibutes and work through those, asking for the particular one you want. This following code is a slight mod from a similar question I found, probably here on SO. (I would like to credit it but I lost it - sorry.)

put this in a try-catch block, passing in a classHandle (the "this" or MyClass.class ) to the method. "classHandle" is of type Class:

```
  String buildDateToReturn = null;
  try
  {
     String path = classHandle.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
     JarFile jar = new JarFile(path);  // or can give a File handle
     Manifest mf = jar.getManifest();
     final Attributes mattr = mf.getMainAttributes();
     LOGGER.trace(" --- getBuildDate: "
           +"\n\t path:     "+ path
           +"\n\t jar:      "+ jar.getName()
           +"\n\t manifest: "+ mf.getClass().getSimpleName()
           );

     for (Object key : mattr.keySet()) 
     {
        String val = mattr.getValue((Name)key);
        if (key != null && (key.toString()).contains("Build-Date"))
        {
           buildDateToReturn = val;
        }
     }
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  { ... }

  return buildDateToReturn;
```

Comment: With regard to the Package methods, these must be defined in the Manifest using the correct names(.e.g. "Implementation-Version"), which are found in the class java.util.jar.Attributes.Name.  This is not particularly well documented.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use JarURLConnection class :

```
String className = getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class";
String classPath = getClass().getResource(className).toString();
if (!classPath.startsWith("jar")) {
    return DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE;
}

URL url = new URL(classPath);
JarURLConnection jarConnection = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();
Manifest manifest = jarConnection.getManifest();
Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
return attributes.getValue(PROPERTY_NAME);
```

Because in some cases `...class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();` gives path with `vfs:/`, so this should be handled additionally.

Or, with ProtectionDomain:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
if (file.isFile()) {
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file);
    Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
    Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
    return attributes.getValue(PROPERTY_NAME);
}
```