# Running soapUI from jar with GUI

Tags: java, soapui

I want to send GET and POST commands with soapUI. Some time ago I had a jar file, with gui. Unfortunately i can't remember how I started it up. My goal is to launch soapUI from console with the following command which I have already tried: java -jar soapui-4.5.0.jar
But it does not work. It says the main manifest attribute is missing. 
Here is my original error message:

```
kein Hauptmanifestattribut, in soapui-4.5.0.jar
```

In english: 'The main attribute of the manifest is missing".

How to overcome this issue? Can anybody help me? I am working at macbook pro with mac osx with JAVA7.

Comment: A handy utility for checking the manifest is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2201870/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error message is because the SoapUI doesn't specify which is the main class. If it is the GUI you want to launch main class is com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI and if you add that to the end of your command it might start up the GUI.

I would recommend you to have a look in the bin folder of SoapUI. It contains some handy scripts. If you have installed SoapUI from the zip file it is located where you unzipped it. If you installed from the dmg file you can find it in /Applications/SoapUI-/Contents/Resources/app/bin.
soapui.sh will start the GUI. testrunner.sh will run the tests of a SoapUI project. From your question it looks like this is what you want to do.

More information on how to use the testrunner script can be found at http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html

Comment: thanks joel, i was trying to install from dmg, but apple says i can not install it, because it comes from untrusted developer. How to install from dmg? I just downloaded the jar from this location: http://www.soapui.org/repository/eviware/jars/ i am not sure if it is the right jar ? i will try to specify the main class meanwhile ;)

Result:
stimpy$ java -jar soapui-4.5.0.jar com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI
kein Hauptmanifestattribut, in soapui-4.5.0.jar

Comment: This is one of the new features of the newest OS X version. It just states that the package is not signed instead of asking the user if he/she wants to install anyway. To circumvent this, right click the installer icon and click open when the security dialog is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you verify if the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file contains the `Main-Class: xxx` attribute (and if it does, is there an empty line at the end of file?)? If not put that there to be able to run it with `java -jar soapui-4.5.0.jar`.

The other method is to type the name of the class to run at the command line, i.e. `java -jar soapui-4.5.0.jar foo.bar.baz.Main`.

Comment: rlegendi thanks for help, i do not have manifest, i am do not knowing about the inside structure of the jar. I remember that i started the jar, that had some years before by doubleclick or from command line.