# Icon Image of Application JAR under Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, icons

I Have problem with displaying my ICON IMAGE in Application JAR using Linux Ubuntu.

No problem in Windows or Mac OS.

No exception displayed, but i don't get the image in the Linux unity launcher bar.

```
 BufferedImage logo;
    try {
        logo = ImageIO.read((InputStream) Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("com/econorma/ui/resources/logo.png")); 
        getMainFrame().setIconImage(logo);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        getMainFrame().setIconImage(null);
    }
```

Comment: Try to put a `/` before your path: `/com/econorma/ui/resources/logo.png`. Just a wild guess thoughm usually apps that run in MAC OS run on linux without problems too.

Comment: What is the problem? If you get an Exception, post the stack trace. If not, describe the symptoms better! :-)

Comment: Also putting the backslash before the package not work here

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the problem is that `JFrame.setIconImage(..)` doesn't do what you expect on Linux when run from JAR? But it works if you run from command line or IDE? I deleted my answer and re-tagged the question to fit with this understanding.

Comment: Launching from IDE or from runnable JAR don't show icon image ONLY using Linux. Same JAR is running on Mac OS and Windows and the factory icon image is show normally.

Comment: That's not the most effective way to catch an exception. Use something that will actually debug the situation.

Comment: Verify that your JAR actually contains the resource, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2201870/230513).