# Listing available classes in current classpath using a command line tool

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I need to check if a specific class is available from current directory using a default JRE/JDK command line tool.

I could build my own class to list it or check if a specific class is reacheble from current directory and current CLASSPATH environment variable,  but this option is not available since I need to check if a specific class name is available or not in a protected production environment (read only).

Comment: If you are running from a JAR, check the manifest's `Class-Path` attribute.

Comment: That's the point @trashgod . I want to check the class availability for an environment,  not if it's present in a specific jar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `javap`:

```
$ javap java.lang.String
Compiled from "String.java"
public final class java.lang.String implements java.io.Serializable
[...]


$ javap no.such.Class
Error:  class not found: no.such.Class
```

Comment: possible to do this, in case you're trying to find a class on specific jar files. `javap -cp "file1.jar:file2.jar" com.example.ClassYouLookFor`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-verbose` option of the [`java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) command and search for the fully qualified name of a specific class.

```
$ java -verbose -jar MyProgram.jar | grep "java.lang.String"
[Loaded java.lang.String from /Library/Java/…/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.StringBuffer from /Library/Java/…/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
…
```

Addendum: *I want to check the class availability for an environment.*

If you are running from the `java` command line, either the paths specified in the `-classpath` option or the `CLASSPATH` environment variable will be searched. If you are running from a JAR, the manifest's `Class-Path` attribute, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2198525/230513), supplants these settings.

If you are trying to find a required JAR that may *not* be accessible in these ways, you'll have to search the file system. I use a combination of `find`, `jar` and `grep`, typically focussing on paths defined  in system properties such as `java.endorsed.dirs` and `java.ext.dirs`; several related approaches are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1342894/230513).