# JFreeChart not working on an executable JAR file?

Tags: netbeans, jar, jfreechart

I have a program which uses the JFreeChart, and it works perfectly fine on NetBeans. However, when I clean and build it into an executable JAR file and open it, I get the following error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKz3o.png)

I have the option to copy dependent libraries when building the program checked, and the required libraries have been copied onto the classpath:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rYXU.png)

Is there anything obvious that I've forgotten to do? How can I fix this?

Comment: Check the [JAR's manifest and content](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) as built, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2198525/230513).

Comment: I did, and I've added the required JARs to the classpath in the manifest, using help from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html but it still doesn't work?

Comment: I just found two dozen working examples in my library, e.g. Apache POI and JFreeChart; you might search for a working example and compare your approach.