# Class not found Java

Tags: java, class, javafx, mainclass

I created artifacts and when starting the program I get the error Class com.abstudio.fakture.MainActivity not found.
When I run a program through the IDE it does everything right.

IDE: Intelij IDEA
JavaFX
Java 8

Manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.abstudio.fakture.MainActivity
```

MainActivity is in path: src/main/java/com/abstudio/fakture/MainActivity

When in cmd I run the command "jar tf ePDV.jar"
i see that the com/abstudio/fakture/MainActivity  path is compiled with other classes, interfaces, etc.

My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'idea'
}
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.abstudio.fakture.MainActivity'
        )
    }
}
sourceSets.main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src/main/java' //assume that your source codes are inside this path
    }
    resources {
        srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/resources']
        exclude "**/*.java"
    }
}


dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:8.0.10'
    implementation group: 'de.jensd', name: 'fontawesomefx', version: '8.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.22'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf
    implementation group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.13.2'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.derby', name: 'derby', version: '10.14.1.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx
    implementation group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '8.40.18'

    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.7'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.8.0'



}
mainClassName = 'com.abstudio.fakture.MainActivity'
```

In project structures Application class is com.abstudio.fakture.MainActivity

[Artifacts and manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxtfY.png)

[Artifacts JavaFX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JMgS.png)

[Compiled classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hnxo.png)

How to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Seems like the class is not inside your JAR. Check that!

Comment: Also check your manifest _in situ_, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2198525/230513).

Comment: no screenshots of plain text please.. and what do you mean by _compiled classes_ (you are showing a list of source file names)?

Comment: Explain in your question what do you mean by "when starting the program". This can mean a lot of different things.

Answer (score 0):

One way to address this is to simply start over from scratch using an alternate method.

This is not an easy task, but will probably give a decent outcome if you can manage it:

1. Create a [new JavaFX project using the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).
2. Use recent software, JDK 17.0.2 and JavaFX 17.0.2 and jfoenix 9, font awesomefx 9, as well as up-to-date versions of other software.
3. Use Maven to build the project instead of Gradle, because it is easier unless you really know what you are doing.
4. Copy your existing code into the project created by the wizard and reimport the updated maven pom to get all the dependencies synchronized.
5. Update module-info.Java file to define your app module requirements,
6. The latest versions of most of the libraries you defined will be modular and linkable, ones that are not you will need to patch to add module info.
7. If it is too difficult to get modularity working, delete the module-info and follow instructions at [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX).
8. Test and debug until it works.
9. Do not create a fat jar that includes JavaFX.
10. Use a jlink zip format via the openjfx-maven-plugin or use jpackage to package the app using JPackageScriptFX.

Because you are sharing similar libraries, also see:

- [Load custom components in scenebuilder 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70985646/load-custom-components-in-scenebuilder-17)

Which has info on the library versions to use and recommended dev approach (a lot of the info in the answer is relevant to you,  regardless of whether you use SceneBuilder on not).